# Classifying spaces of $E_1$-spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces, loop-spaces

I'm a newbie trying to understand May's recognition principle on $E_1$-spaces. In May's paper *The Geometry of Iterated Loop Spaces*, the classifying space of an $E_1$-space $X$ is defined to be $B(\Sigma, E_1, X)$. Is there a simple way to see how this coincides with the usual classifying space $BG$ in the case where $X=G$ is a topological group?

Comment: What is your construction of the usual classifying space?

Comment: @ConnorMalin the bar construction

Comment: I don't recall all of the conventions, but it may be helpful to note that there is an operad equivalence $E_1 \to A$, where $A$ is the associative operad.

Comment: @JustinYoung even when $E_1$ is replaced by the associative operad, I still can't see how this gives the usual BG...

Comment: I found a reference, see sections 7 and 8 of Fiedorowicz: https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT9580/v18/documents/fiedorowicz-classifying-spaces-of-topological-monoids-and-categories-amer-j-math-1984.pdf The paper is called Classifying spaces of topological monoids and categories.

Comment: Thank you @JustinYoung, I'll check it out!